# SqlException thrown for invalid conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, wix, ssms

I'm using C# for a custom action in wix, which works fine. The custom action essentially just runs sql scripts based on the parameters passed to a method.

One of the scripts I'm running populates one of my tables with data, if there's nothing in it, and looks something like this:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Table]) = 0
BEGIN

INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([ItemId], [Description]) VALUES (N'<<GUID>>', NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([ItemId], [Description]) VALUES (N'<<GUID>>', N'The 2nd Item')

...

END
```

In this instance `<<GUID>>` is something like `e00104e4-7e5f-4563-9356-30732d5ca57e` - these scripts were generated from data exports of SQL Server 2008 R2 using the corresponding edition of Management Studio.

When I run this script in Management Studio, it works fine and as expected, all the data gets inserted if there is nothing already there. Running it via the C# code, however, and I get the following exception:

`Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier`

As the only `uniqueidentifier` column in the table, this has to be the ItemId column, but I can't figure out why this is happening, or how to resolve the issue, and the last hour searching online hasn't given anything either.

**EDIT**

I should add that these SQL queries are located in a file, which the C# code then reads the content of as the SQL query. I don't really want to have to modify them if I can help it, as it adds an extra step that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Could you check what is actually passed to the DB via Profiler tool? Please paste it, so we could investigate some more

Comment: You need to check what values are comes in variable which is used to store GUID data in C# code. Does that variable contain correct value? and check the same value is passed into the query via parameter in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue now. Turns out that one of the scripts was out of date, and the ID of **that** table had been changed from an `nvarchar` to a `uniqueidentifier`.

2 things then happened, the first was that nobody else updated the script that populated that tables default data. The 2nd was that wix (or the custom action running the SQL, I'm not sure exactly which) was reporting the error after the first script, which happens to have a very similar table structure.

So, in all, I should've spotted what the issue was sooner. Instead, I get to have made a fool out of myself on SA for not doing so. Thanks for the answers anyway, hopefully they'll be of use to someone who stumbles across this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a conversion function on T-SQL for `uniqueidentifier` columns
Try with this:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table] ([ItemId], [Description]) VALUES (CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,N'<<GUID>>'), N'The 2nd Item')
```

Comment: I've just updated the original question as to why this isn't really the ideal solution for what I have. It would work normally, but I still find it strange that management studio runs the same SQL without an issue.

Comment: Well, seems there is no way to pass a string like that without changes back to SQLServer. I have tried to find a way to tell SSMS to insert a CONVERT in its output script but with no success. Probably it thinks that the script is for a copy of itself to use. On the other side if the uniqueidentifier is passed as string inside a SqlCommand it fails with the mentioned error. I think you should implement a transform before submitting your INSERT to SqlServer via ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting issue. You aren't using Visual Studio 2008 by any chance? It's possible that the driver you are using is out of date.

Comment: No, I'm using VS 2010, I've figured out what the issue was now anyway. I should've probably considered checking it sooner too...See the answer below